# "Learned" vs "ever learned."

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between the two? For example:

> One plus one, that was the first equation she had (ever) learned.

How does the "ever" change the sentence?

Answer (score 2):

Ever would in some cases be used as emphasis, for dramatic affect. For example "Oh my this is the nicest cake I have ever had!" meaning they have never had a nicer cake. However if they were to say "This is the nicest cake I have had" it does not define a timescale or is as dramatic.